# jQuery .click() not firing inside .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an interface using Bootstrap tabs and I'm trying to trigger a tab click when an asynchronously inserted link is clicked. (Clicking a link in a content tab should trigger a tab change.) I have a working solution, but want to know why my first solution doesn't.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="content-tabs">
    <a id="results-tab" class="tab active" href="#results-content" aria-controls="results-tab">Results</a>
    <a id="directions-tab" class="tab" href="#directions-content" aria-controls="directions-tab">Directions</a>
</div>
<div class="content-border-tab tab-content col-sm-12">
    <div id="results-content" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <!-- 'Get Directions' links get inserted here with a class of 'directions' -->
    </div>
    <div id="directions-content" class="tab-pane fade">
        <!-- driving directions are inserted here via JS -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my broken Javascript:

```
$('#results-content').on('click', '.directions', function(e) {
    $('#directions-tab').click();
});

$('.content-tabs a').click(function(e) {
    // do whatever
});
```

I have a working solution, I just don't understand why the above code doesn't work and the below code does:

```
$('#results-content').on('click', '.directions', function(e) {
    var click = new MouseEvent('click', {});
    document.getElementById('directions-tab').dispatchEvent(click);
});

$('.content-tabs a').click(function(e) {
    // do whatever
});
```

Your help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Also what's the point of including the code `$('.content-tabs a').click(function(e) {...` in both examples?

Comment: Can't really reproduce the issue -> https://jsfiddle.net/qxy5Lbaa/

Comment: Any reason you go about this the complicated way, instead of just using the `tab`method to directly show the tab want ...?

Comment: No errors in the console... I'm triggering the second click because that's what toggles the 'active' class on the tab itself. Toggling the visible content is only one of the two actions needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your working example adds a new click handler which also be removed when you add new content and then reattached each time however you should be able to also bind it like the following example and should work.

```
$(document).on('click', '#results-content .directions', function(e) {
    $('#directions-tab').click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it looks like your solution only changes the target selector, not the behavior. For some reason, explicitly creating and binding the click event is the only way that works.